# Swift iOS 13.3 bad GPS when speed is nearly 0

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have an app that tracks the journeys of the user. 
I noticed that in background, from iOS 13.3, the system slows down the sending of locations when the speed slows down. In case of high speed, the location are sent every second. Is this possible? Could it be a bug? This is my location manager:

```
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
locationManager.activityType = .other
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```

Comment: Location updates are sent when there is a location change, not on a strict tim basis. With horizontal accuracy being 5m, at best, you would expect the location update rate to decrease as speed approaches 0

Comment: it's correct. but until iOS 13.3, the location updates coming also when the speed was 0.

Comment: Maybe Apple realised that this wasn’t efficient and made an improvement?

Comment: i suppose. i've the same code and i tested 1 year. but now i've more problems

Comment: Why have you got the activity type set to other if you are tracking a journey? Why not `.otherNavigation` or `.automotiveNavigation`?

Comment: `.other` should not stop the GPS polling. I need one point for second

Comment: Who knows what the activity type does, but Apple obviously uses it for *something*, otherwise the property wouldn’t exist. Perhaps they decide that they can lower the update rate